# Work, Heat, mass flow rate and inexact differentials

Tags: thermodynamics, work, tensor-calculus

I have been trying to understand about work, heat and mass flow rate and its definition as inexact differentials.
I came across this site with lecture notes which explain inexact differential: 
http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/sm1/lectures/node36.html.
Can you help me understand why in equation 145 gives a direction (gradient) instead of a slope?
Also, how is the equation 147 arrived at.
Thank you.

Edited:
In

[image: How is eq 145 a gradient?]

How is equation 145 giving a direction(gradient) and not a slope?.

Also here

[image: Please help me with eq 147]

how is equation 147 arrived at?

Edit2

How does the equation

$$dy/dx=-X'/Y'$$

Represent a gradient instead of a slope? Here X' and Y' are general equation of x and y.

Also how is

$$Y'∂σ/∂x=X'∂σ/∂y=X'Y'/τ$$

Not understanding how $$X'Y'/τ$$ is arrived at.

Any explanation for this is welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: Please, can someone help me out with this question?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that we do have an [equation editor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) built into the site, which will allow you to write the necessary equations into the post so you won't have to rely on users reading an external resource (generally looked down on) in order to understand the question.

Comment: Hello Kyle, thank you for your thoughts. I will use the equation editor.

Comment: This might help, https://carnotcycle.wordpress.com/2013/06/01/on-exact-and-inexact-differentials/

Comment: @GRANZER: taking screenshots is not at all what I had suggested...

Comment: A shortcut that might help. Go to Wikipedia on the same topic as your question and copy and paste  the appropriate, or closest equations  into the answer box. With a little study, you will be able to tweak them and have real Mathjax,  not a copy of a page, using $$ at each end of the equations.  This page is useful https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Countto10, Thank you for the resource...it helped me remind myself why while energy itself is a state function and between any two fixed states gives a constant value, heat and work which represents the transfer of this same energy can have different values between the same 2 states and how this all is balanced out in first law.

Comment: @KyleKanos, since I could not figure out how to include the equations here I took screenshots. Hope screenshots are not against community guidelines.

Comment: @GRANZER they're not against guidelines, but they're usually looked down upon since we have a built in equation editor (directions included in my first link).

Comment: @Countto10 Thank you. I used word to write down the equations instead.

Comment: @KyleKanos Did not see the link included in your first comment...sorry about that. Thank you for your inputs.

Comment: Can some one help me out with this doubt please ?

Comment: Really do want to understand this. If anyone of u could help me out or point me in the direction where I could find an answer?